# I am not able to get alias name while using "Create external table" command in netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

1. I am not able to get the alias name for the first column
   For example my query is :

   Create External Table '' USING (DELIMETER ',' INCLUDEHEADER REMOTESOURCE 'YES') as
   Select 'ABC' as TABLENAME,
   Count(1) AS Row_Count
   From ABC;

In this case my output in .csv file is :

```
,ROW_COUNT
ABC,20000
```

**Here I am not getting the first alias which is *'TABLENAME'***

2. I am not able to get alias name when my select statement contains "COALESCE" function
   For example my query is :

   Create External Table '' USING (DELIMETER ',' INCLUDEHEADER REMOTESOURCE 'YES') as
   Select 'ABC' as TABLENAME, 
   Coalesce(Sum(COLUMN1),0) as COLUMN1, 
   Sum(COLUMN2) as COLUMN2, 
   Coalesce(Sum(COLUMN3),0) as COLUMN3 
   From ABC;

In this case my output in .csv file is :

```
,,COLUMN2,
ABC,2123,4535,5652
```

**Here I am not getting the column name of the first alias and the alias where I have used *'COALESCE'* function**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the SELECT part of the query in a simple sub-select.  For example:

```
Create External Table '' USING (DELIMETER ',' INCLUDEHEADER REMOTESOURCE 'YES') as

SELECT * FROM  (          /* this line added */

     Select 'ABC' as TABLENAME,
     Count(1) AS Row_Count From ABC

) SUB1                   /* this line added */
```